# Can't create a 'real' type array in Verilog

Tags: arrays, parameters, verilog, icarus

I've tried creating a 'real' type value array in the following way in Icarus Verilog:

```
parameter width = 10;
shortreal b [width-1:0] = {0.0181,0.0487,0.1227,0.1967,0.2273,0.1967,0.1227,0.0487,0.0181};
```

Gives the following error:

```
error: Cannot assign to array b. Did you forget a word index?
```

I went through the icarus verilog src code error messages and the explanation to  this one is "Special case: The l-value is an entire memory, or array
slice". This is, in fact, an error in l-values. Detect the
situation by noting if the index count is less than the
array dimensions (unpacked)", which I assume means that the array index size differs from the declared one `[width-1:0]`, which isn't true if I understand.

I've also tried:

```
parameter width = 10;
parameter [32:0] b [width-1:0] = {0.0181,0.0487,0.1227,0.1967,0.2273,0.1967,0.1227,0.0487,0.0181};
```

but without any success.

Using Icarus Verilog with `-g2012` flag (for SV support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only legal to use so-called array concatenation if you fill the entire array. You array have 10 elements, but there are only 9 on the right hand side:

```
parameter width = 10;
shortreal b [width-1:0] = {0.0181,0.0487,0.1227,0.1967,0.2273,0.1967,0.1227,0.0487,0.0181,0.0181};
```

Comment: That's the case with commercial simulators, anyway. Icarus doesn't seem to like it either way. https://www.edaplayground.com/x/9AQG

Comment: Also,should I then use the I/O file operation to accomplish this? Let's say,put the numbers on a .txt and then put those on a memory of the same dimensions as above?

Comment: @Ginjas That's up to you. If these numbers are being written to a file from some other program then I would imagine it would be better to write some Verilog/SV to read that file rather than having to paste those values into your code. (Unless the code were synthesisable, in which I doubt your synthesiser would make sense of it.)